Fabric bleaching / dyeing question
I just purchased this top at a consignment shop. 95% polyester with 5% elastic. Light tan with muted pink and green stripes. Despise the colors love the shirt. How do I either a) bleach it all white b) bleach to almost white and then dye it another color or c) if bleaching not possible, just add darker colors and dye it a striped darker color.

Polyester fabric can only be dyed at temperatures above 100 degrees Celsius (160-200 degrees). Therefore, you can't dye it at home using common household utensils. Even if you manage to somehow reach the required temperature, polyester is dyed using disperse dyes, which are very challenging to work with. There is a high chance that if an unprofessional person dyes the fabric, it will result in patches of color.
Bleaching is also not a good option because bleaching polyester is tricky. So, I wouldn't recommend trying that either.
I would also advise you to return it or give it someone who likes the color.

PES or PP(at functional clothes) are dyed in bulk volume and these dyes are not accessible to bleaching to be discolored (safe the very surface).
As the test, you can try to bleech the polyester from a colored PET bottle.
It is possible that any bleaching attempt could have unpredictable results, because of the elastic components, depending on the texture of fabric. Similarly to coloring.
Better would be to return it or giving it to someone who likes the colors.
